# getchar() and the enter button understanding how it really works

Tags: c, shell

I have written the below function (while I was reading the Ritchie book on C) to get a single line from the command line. It does what it should do, and I understand how it works, but I wanted to dig a bit deeper.

```
int getLine(char arr[], int max) {
    int c, i;
    for (i = 0; i < max - 1 && (c = getchar())!= EOF && c!= '\n'; ++i) {
        arr[i] = c;
    }
    if(c == '\n') {
        arr[i] = c;
    }
    arr[i+1] = '\0';
    return i; /*length without '\n'*/
}
```

my question is about the loop, let's say we have a blank command line, and it is waiting for the user to enter something because the first getchar() is called in the loop, let's say then that the user entered the following:

```
h
```

My guess about what happens then, is that getchar() stores that 'h' in arr[] without the user actually pressing enter.

so if the user keeps typing:

```
hello
```

'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' and 'o' will be stored in arr[] without the user actually pressing enter and getchar will have been called a total of 6 times, the last one being after the 'o'. And then when the user presses enter, getchar() will store '\n' in arr[], am I right? Is this exactly how it works? So I guess the question is

does getchar() need enter to do what it does?

thanks

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, and step through the code line by line, while watching all involved variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getchar()` does not return anything until you flush the input, for which you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> or insert `EOF`, on a linux terminal that is achieved by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and windows console <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> will do it.

Comment: thanks, but even if it doesn't return anything, it is still called and still picks the letter up am I right, because it has to be called over and over again

Comment: Yes, it returns each character in turn. But not until after it gets a bufferful. Remember, C was created on/for computers that had serial TTYs.

Comment: so the last character of getchar will always be the '\n' then

Comment: No, because you can press `Ctrl+D`/`Ctrl+Z` and `EOF` will be recieved, so there wont be a `'\n'`, but usually you press enter/return, except if they have a special meaning, for example `python`'s console expects `quit()` or `Ctrl+D`/`Ctrl+Z` to exit.

Comment: @Gravity No, the last character will always be `\0` in a valid C string. Nowhere does it say that all I/O functions must have newlines following them.

Comment: In other words, `getchar()` blocks and waits for input. Only once you enter a certain number of characters will it start inserting them into the array and continuing the loop.

Comment: well if you just stop the flow by Ctrl+D there will not be a '\0' at the end unless you put it there, I think many functions do put it there like scanf, but this above function is something I wrote so there won't be '\0' unless I put it there, which I do:)

Comment: @Gravity exactly, that's why I though that the first comment by SevenBits had extra information, because you are aware of what the `last character` means.

Comment: it is hard for me to properly word the question, is it one getchar() for one letter? or does the same getchar() accumulate the letters when it is called over and over again, I mean is it like a same function with its status kept in between calls like a static variable?

Comment: @Gravity letter != character

Comment: @iharob Technically, though, if you did not terminate the string with a `\0` character, it would not be valid. But yes, just using `getchar()` can produce an invalid string. I did not properly understand the question, I apologize.

Comment: @SevenBits thanks I am aware I mean char, character, I just want to know if the same getchar() collects all the chars like a garbage-man,  so in the above code, there will be only one getchar() returning not multiple?

Comment: @Gravity Insert a `printf` call before the line `arr[i] = c;` and then flush `stdout` to see your yourself. :)

Comment: but judging from @iharob's comments, it is only one getchar() returning, because it only returns after I flush the input, so getchar takes the chars, does whatever with them, and only returns in proper order to some place else, when I flush the input